# Span a column over more than one row using Bootstrap v4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, bootstrap-4

I have a site with a small banner that I would like to put a picture in. I am using HTML and the Bootstrap (v4) CSS/JS package. In my banner, I have three different headings, one which is h1 and the two below that are h7. This is what my page currently looks like:

[image]

And this is what I want it to look like, roughly:

[image]

The white lines are just so that one can see each column in each row. From the first picture, you can see that the column that contains the picture is pushing the other two down.
So how would I go about making the picture-column span more than one row?

For reference, here is my current markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fenix Prime's</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
    <div class="container bg-dark">
      <div class="pl-3 pr-3 pt-3 pb-0 row bg-dark text-light">
        <div class="col-9 border">
          <h1>Fenix Prime</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 border offset-2">
          <img class="float-right" src="dp.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row pt-0 pb-0 pl-3 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
        <div class="col-9 border">
          <h7>Vim dico aperiri deleniti in. Sint quaestio repudiandae quo et.</h7>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row pt-0 pb-3 pl-3 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
        <div class="col-9 border">
          <h7>An per amet everti senserit, cum te insolens oportere consequat.</h7>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr/>

      <div class="p-3 row bg-dark text-light">
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th style="font-weight: bold;">Introduction.</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, brute oratio eu qui, quem dolorum cotidieque eam an. Offendit philosophia ex eos, ius ut incorrupte disputationi. Eum affert soleat apeirian et, mei aperiam moderatius te. Oblique prodesset voluptatibus an quo,
                purto omnium consequuntur eu vel. Veritus maiestatis sit no, in vis rationibus ullamcorper, ignota labitur cu has.
                <br/> Clita timeam nominavi in his. Propriae vivendum similique ne est, pri omnes dolore ei.</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The answer to your question depends on how you want to stack those elements on small screens. Or do you just want a solution for larger screens and don't care how they stack on smaller screens?

Comment: I will worry about smaller screens later, but eventually I want it to be smooth on all sizes.

Comment: "smooth"?? There is no such thing. You need to define that.

Comment: @fenix Prime, share your css as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is accomplished simply by nesting i.e. you are nesting the row-column pairs for the h7 elements inside the column for the h1 element like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
    <div class="container bg-dark">
        <div class="pl-3 pr-3 pt-3 pb-0 row bg-dark text-light">
            <div class="col-9 border">
                <h1>Fenix Prime</h1>
                <div class="row pt-0 pb-0 pl-3 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
                    <div class="col-9 border">
                        <h7>Vim dico aperiri deleniti in. Sint quaestio repudiandae quo et.</h7>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row pt-0 pb-3 pl-3 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
                    <div class="col-9 border">
                        <h7>An per amet everti senserit, cum te insolens oportere consequat.</h7>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 border offset-2">
                <img class="float-right img-fluid2" src="https://placehold.it/120" />
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <hr/>

        <div class="p-3 row bg-dark text-light">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="font-weight: bold;">Introduction.</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, brute oratio eu qui, quem dolorum cotidieque eam an. Offendit philosophia ex eos, ius ut incorrupte disputationi. Eum affert soleat apeirian et, mei aperiam moderatius te. Oblique prodesset voluptatibus an quo,
                            purto omnium consequuntur eu vel. Veritus maiestatis sit no, in vis rationibus ullamcorper, ignota labitur cu has.
                            <br/> Clita timeam nominavi in his. Propriae vivendum similique ne est, pri omnes dolore ei.</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just make sure you always use row-column pairs together because they are designed to work together as a pair.

Comment: The two h7 elements could be put into the same column if you separate them with this: `<div class="w-100"></div>` that's a div with 100% width.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your `<H7>` titles right under the `<h1>` so they sitauted together in one `div`.

Comment: I agree, that is definitely possible. But I was using more of an example on how to get a column to span more than one row, I think that would be handy to know.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of the

```
<div class="col-9 border">
     <h1>Fenix Prime</h1>
</div>
```

and the

```
 <div class="col-1 border offset-2">
      <img class="float-right" src="dp.png" />
    </div>
```

Adding the `style="float:right"` to the `div` containing the image

```html
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
        <div class="container bg-dark">
            <div class="pl-3 pr-3 pt-3 pb-0 row bg-dark text-light">
                <div style="float:right" class="col-1 border offset-2">
                    <img src="http://www.csuchico.edu/~nwylde/250/symbolsnet/images-3.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-9 border">
                    <h1>Fenix Prime</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pt-0 pb-0 pl-3 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
                <div class="col-9 border">
                    <h7>Vim dico aperiri deleniti in. Sint quaestio repudiandae quo et.</h7>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pt-0 pb-3 pl-3 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
                <div class="col-9 border">
                    <h7>An per amet everti senserit, cum te insolens oportere consequat.</h7>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr/>

            <div class="p-3 row bg-dark text-light">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="font-weight: bold;">Introduction.</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, brute oratio eu qui, quem dolorum cotidieque eam an. Offendit philosophia
                                ex eos, ius ut incorrupte disputationi. Eum affert soleat apeirian et, mei aperiam moderatius
                                te. Oblique prodesset voluptatibus an quo, purto omnium consequuntur eu vel. Veritus maiestatis
                                sit no, in vis rationibus ullamcorper, ignota labitur cu has.
                                <br/> Clita timeam nominavi in his. Propriae vivendum similique ne est, pri omnes dolore ei.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: have u replaced the 2 divs with one another?